# Order of asynchronous HTTP requests

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-http

Basically I have a component with a list of elements and I have a detail component, where you can edit or add a new element.

After I add an element via a http service (this.myservice is based upon hero.service.ts from the documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) to my server. Then I directly jump back to the list of element component.

I use Zone, so that ngOnInit is called. [Angular 2 ngOnInit not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936535/angular-2-ngoninit-not-called)

The problem is that quite often the list of elements is not updated with the new element yet. I suppose the order of the asynchronous HTTP requests get mixed up.

How would a good solution look like?

```
export class DetailElemComp {
    this.myService.addElem(this.elem)
      .subscribe(
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['ListComponent']));
}
export class ListOfElemComp {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getElems()
          .subscribe(
            elems => this.elems = elems,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, like you said, it's an asynchronous request. So if you want to do something after the request has finished, I'd suggest moving that logic into the `onCompleted` callback lambda of the [`subscribe`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) function like so:

```js
export class DetailElemComp {
    this.myService.addElem(this.elem)
      .subscribe(
        data => null,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
        () => this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['ListComponent']))
      );
}
```

Code below that `subscribe` call will otherwise run before the callbacks inside of the `subscribe` method do.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is very neat and simple.