# ngOnInit doesn't run until after I navigate to another component

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In my NativeScript app, I have the route set up as

```
export const routes = [
    { path: "",  component: AppComponent},
    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent},
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
    { path: "news" , component: NewsComponent}
];
```

After a user is logged in through firebase the user is auto redirected to the `HomeComponent`. I should mention that I have a user service that gets fired from the `AppComponent Constuctor` that determines if a user is already logged in then redirects them to login or home.

I have console.log() spread across the component to see when things gets triggered so I can try to figure out where to place the code.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import {RouterExtensions} from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

@Component ({
    selector : "home",
    templateUrl: "./pages/home/home.html",
    styleUrls: ["./pages/home/home.css"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    private router;

    constructor(page: Page, router: RouterExtensions) {

        console.log("HOME CONSTRUCTOR TRIGGERED");
        page.actionBarHidden = false;
        this.router = router;
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        console.log("HOME NGONIT TRIGGERED");
    }

    goToNews(){
        this.router.navigate(["/news"]);
    }

}
```

In `home.html` I have a button that triggers `goToNews()`.  When I load up the app, I can see in my console when `HomeComponent` constructor gets triggered, but I never see `ngOnInit` get triggered. The strange thing is that when I click on the button to navigate to `/news`, this is when I see the HomeComponent `ngOnInit` fire in my console. Is this the way it's suppose to work?

This all comes down to a "big picture understanding" where I'm trying to figure out the best place to put my logic down when `HomeComponent` gets loaded. I read that putting it in the constructor was a bad idea and having it in `ngOnInit` is ideal however I don't see how this can make any sense if `ngOnInit` only gets triggered after I try to navigate away from the component.

Please help me understand this.

**UPDATE:** I added a console.log to `ngOnInit` in `AppComponent` and this does get fired when the app first loads. So it must be the navigation in the services that is causing `ngOnInit` to not fire in `HomeComponent`.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem: `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit` only get called when the app loads. Any subsequent navigation to other components doesn't trigger these methods in those components.

Comment: @CarlosMermigas My conclusion as of now is that navigation via a service does not trigger ngOnInit, so I had to pass back a variable to the component and have the navigation done there.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting the router.navigate() into a separate "Zone":

import:

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
```

inject:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { ... }
```

apply:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    this.router.navigate(["/news"]);
});
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936535/angular-2-ngoninit-not-called).