# Component code not called after navigation in Angular 4

Tags: angular, error-handling, navigation, router

I'm trying to implement error handler using Angular 5.0.0.

In the error handler implementing `ErrorHandler` interface I change the current route to the error component route:

```
router.navigate(['/error'], {queryParams: errorWithContextInfo});
```

The URL in the browser bar changes, the component HTML is displayed, `constructor` is called, `onInit` is not called, the member variables are not accessible in the view (always empty, even when they are public and have default value).

Then, when I hit F5, error route is loaded properly, all member variables changed in the constructor on onInit hook are accessible in the view as expected.

How can I fix this behavior?
(queryParams should be accessible in the component view right after navigation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force change detection when navigation completes using NgZone.

Inject it in the constructor:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router, private zone: NgZone) {}
```

then call the navigation action like this:

```
this.zone.run(() => router.navigate(['/error'], {queryParams: params}));
```

See [Angular 2 ngOnInit not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936535/angular-2-ngoninit-not-called) and [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18254) for details.