# Detect Change in Angular binding with same name but different value?

Tags: angular

I am working with profile image change api. Each time I change image I get changed image back from server but with the **same url** (*say test.jpeg*).

```
  url: string; 

 <img [src]="url" />

 url : test.jpeg   // url returned from server on image change first time
 url : test.jpeg   // url returned from server on image change second time
 url : test.jpeg   // url returned from server on image change third time
```

Though server returns different image angular is not able to detect as there is no change in url. How to solve this ?

Comment: Do you use any changeDetectionStrategy?

Comment: share code that fetch/ update the profile image.

Comment: you need to assign new value to url when the API response is arrived.

Comment: The old value(url) and New value(url) are same from API Response. Only content of image inside server changes

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936535/angular-2-ngoninit-not-called/35937062#35937062

Answer (score 1):

easy way to do that is adding some fake query params.

```
 get src() {
   return this._imageSrc + '?q=' + this.hash;
 }

 pictureWasUpdated() {
  this.hash = Math.random().toString(16)
 }
```