# Redirection problem from Springboot to Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, url

Our team make a web application with Angular frontend and Springboot backend. The procurer asked Google Authentication in case of user login. On the login component there is an anchor tag, after a click the google page jump up and we can choose our profile. After that the Google send the user data to Springboot, where it validates that and then it creates a token.

My problem is in Angular we use *HashLocationStrategy*, there is an auth component with this url:
**http://localhost:4200/#/auth**, where the token in route parameters is waited. In normal way it would look like "http://localhost:4200/#/auth?token=25jlsjflsfdlslfj....".
In Springboot there is also a variable: public static final String ALTERNATIVE_REDIRECT_URI = **"http://localhost:4200/#/auth"**;
But it can't work with #, because with these settings the Spring sends back the token to the basic route, for a moment the ?token=..... is shown on the url and after the page is rerendered. Without the HashLocationStrategy it works well (**http://localhost:4200/auth**). Could you recommend a solution? How do I need to declare the Url in Springboot?

Answer (score 0):

Answer

Angular runs its code in a patched zone where addEventListener(), setTimeout(), and other async APIs are patched to notify Angular when async action has happened to rerun change detection. This makes change detection quite efficient. When code is called that somehow circuments Angulars zone, Angulars change detection doesn't kick in. If a method (even one from an Angular component or similar) is called from code that was invoked outside Angulars zone, everything runs outside the zone until this event is fully processed. With zone.run(...) you force execution back into Angulars zone.

[visit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936535/angular-2-ngoninit-not-called/35937062#comment59531723_35937062)